# Javascript event change style with sass mixin

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, sass, width

I am working on a site with a sidebar. When you press the button the sidebar comes in from the left and pushes the main body away.

The sidebar has a width of 280px and a max width of 80% (for mobile devices). At the moment my javascript looks like this:

```
  // Left menu moves in the view
  $('.left-menu').toggleClass('in-view');
  // Moves the body to the right 280px
  $('.content-wrapper').toggleClass('to-right');

  // to-right in css
  .to-right {
      @include translate(280px, 0);
  }

  // Mixin
  @mixin transform($transforms) {
   -moz-transform: $transforms;
   -o-transform: $transforms;
   -ms-transform: $transforms;
   -webkit-transform: $transforms;
   transform: $transforms;
  }

  @mixin translate($x,
  $y) {
      @include transform(translate($x, $y));
  }
```

This works great on desktops and tablets but on mobile this causes a problem. to-right moves the body 280px but if the 80% is lower than 280px there will be space left..

How can I make it so that when you open the sidebar it moves the body exactly the width of the sidebar? Ofcourse you can just do:

```
.css('-moz-transform', 'sidebar_width')
.css('-o-transform', 'sidebar_width')
.css('-ms-transform', 'sidebar_width')
.css('-webkit-transform', 'sidebar_width')
.css('transform', 'sidebar_width')
```

But I really don't think that's the right way to do it..

Is there a nicer way to fix this? Some kind of Javascript custom mixin event?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: What .to-right is doing ? Can you add a fiddle please ?

Comment: Added the to-right code + the mixin

Comment: What does this have to do with Sass?  This is a pure CSS problem, only provide the compiled CSS.

Comment: The problem is that I need a nice alternative for all the prefixes (if there is one) in which I can get the width from the sidebar and use that right away in css

Comment: Yes but cimmanon is right, using sass or not doesn't matter in the end, it's just easier to write. It seems to be a pure css problem and it would be much easier with an example since we don't know what behavior you expect.

Comment: Added a fiddle, open the sidebar and make the output window smaller

Comment: Why did you remove the code from this question?   Linking to a 3rd party site is not acceptable.

Comment: I'm sorry, the other person asked for a fiddle to make my problem clear, code back, fiddle removed.

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear: you can post a link to a demo, but the code in question *must* be in the question itself.  You're not allowed to *only* post a link to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's usually better to keep the css and javascript separate. Media queries are a useful way to provide different styling depending on device properties, like screen size.

```
.in-view {
    width: 280px;
    max-width: 80%;

    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 350px) {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

350px is the screen width at which point 80% = 280px.

Comment: This is a great solution to my problem! Accepted!